# $\{ M_i | i\in J \}$ is a set of maximal ideals of R and $I$ is an ideal of R. Prove that $\cap_{i\in J} M_i +I = \cap_{i\in J} (M_i +I)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

R is commutative ring with unit 1, $\{ M_i | i\in J \}$ is a set of maximal ideals of R and $I$ is an ideal of R. Is it true that $\cap_{i\in J} M_i +I = \cap_{i\in J} (M_i +I)$?

This is just a question I ask myself. So maybe it's not true. If it isn't, can you guys give me an counterexample?

Comment: This is false. Try $R=\mathbb{C}[x]$, polynomial ring, $M_i$ be the collection of maximal ideals of the form $(x-a), a\neq 0$ and $I=(x)$.

Comment: The left hand side is always contained in the right hand side, since if $f\in \cap_{i\in J}M_{i}+I,$ then $f=g+h$, with $g\in\cap_{i\in J}M_{i}$, and $h\in I$. But then $g+h\in M_{i}+I$ for all $i\in J$, hence $f\in\cap_{i\in J}(M_{i}+I)$.